# Execute on the basename of a find command

Tags: command-line, find, basename

Suppose I have a directory structure as follows

```
test
test/a
test/b
```

Now I want to execute a command, such that in the `.` folder I can execute a command on the basename of the files `a` and `b`.

So basically, I want something like this, which I naively tried

```
find test -type f -exec touch `basename {}` \;
```

Only, this does not result in empty files `a` and `b` in the parent directory. Suppose that my touch command can only take a single argument.

This will result in a directory structure like this

```
a
b
test
test/a
test/b
```

I know how to do this in a bash script, but I am interested in single command solution.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve, perhaps with a directory tree before and after.  The phrase "Only, this does not result in empty files a and b in the parent directory." appears to suggest you want to create files while your opening statement suggests the files already exist.

Comment: @Bram I had the impression it follow a bit from my example find command, but I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `execdir` option for `find`: it executes the command you specify in the directory of the file, using only its basename as the argument

From what I gather, you want to create "a" and "b" in the "main" directory. We can do that by combining `$PWD` and the `-execdir` option. Have a look at the solution below. (The `&& find … ls` parts are for output only, so you can see the effects. You'll want to use the command before the `&&`.)

First, I set up the testing environment:

```
-----[ 15:40:17 ] (!6293) [ :-) ] janmoesen@mail ~/stack 
$ mkdir test && touch test/{a,b} && find . -exec ls -dalF {} +
drwxr-xr-x 3 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x 2 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/b
```

This is what happens when you use a simple `-exec` — the original files are touched:

```
-----[ 15:40:30 ] (!6294) [ :-) ] janmoesen@mail ~/stack 
$ find test -type f -exec touch {} \; && find . -exec ls -dalF {} +
drwxr-xr-x 3 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x 2 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/b
```

However, if we combine `$PWD` with the argument placeholder `{}` and use `-execdir`, we achieve what (I think) you want:

```
-----[ 15:40:57 ] (!6295) [ :-) ] janmoesen@mail ~/stack 
$ find test -type f -execdir touch "$PWD/{}" \; && find . -exec ls -dalF {} +
drwxr-xr-x 3 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:41 ./
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:41 ./a
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:41 ./b
drwxr-xr-x 2 janmoesen janmoesen 4096 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 janmoesen janmoesen    0 2012-05-31 15:40 ./test/b
```

Answer (score 5):

Execute bash.

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'touch "${1##*/}"' btouch {} \;
```

Here `${1##*/}` means: remove the longest match from the second argument ending with a `/`, thus keeping everything after the last `/`.

`btouch` can be any dummy name, to make it appear properly in the active processes list (`ps`)

Comment: This one does not work for me. `touch: missing file operand`. Also, what is `1##*` and `btouch`?

Comment: Fixed. Parameter expansion. `$0`.

Comment: This works indeed, can you explain a bit why? Especially this `1##*` Is this to strip the path?

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_beginning

Comment: Found it in the manpage, but this explanation is more comprehensive. `btouch` is still a mystery to me however...

Comment: It's just `$0` for the new process.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use `bash -c 'touch "${0##*/}"' {} \;`

Comment: Because it looks silly. Plus, `$0` shows up in `ps` and the like, so that you can identify the child process.

Answer (score 3):

Try this at your own risk:

```
find test -type f -exec echo touch \"\$\(basename "'{}'"\)\" \; | bash
```

Tested with filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ touch $(find test -type f -exec basename {} \;)
```

Comment: Suppose that my `touch` command only takes one argument at a time?

Comment: Will break on filenames with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke a shell to do a bit of string processing on the path. You can use the `${VARIABLE##PATTERN}` string manipulation construct to strip off a prefix matching `PATTERN` from `VARIABLE` — the pattern `*/` strips off the leading directory names.

```
find test -type f -exec sh -c 'for x; do touch "${x##*/}"; done' _ {} +
```

An alternate method with GNU find is to have it change into the subdirectories. Invoke a shell to change back to the original directory.

```
find test -type f -execdir sh -c 'cd "$0" && touch -- "$@"' "$PWD" {} +
```

Or drop `find` and use zsh. Specifically, add the `t` [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) as a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
touch test/**/*(:t)
```