# Use find command to convert markdown files to html

Tags: bash, find

Lets suppose I have files on my harddisk having extensions as `.md`.

I want to convert all those files to `.html` through `find` and the `-exec` option.

The command to convert a markdown file to html is

```
markdown readme.md > readme.html
```

I am trying to use something like:

```
find / -name "*.md" -type f -exec markdown {} > {}.html \;
```

Of course, the above doesn't work. So, how do I do that using only `find` and `exec`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39654/execute-on-the-basename-of-a-find-command

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to quote around the construct containing `>` because it's a shell special character, like this:

```
find / -name "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c 'markdown "$0" > "$0.html"' {} \;
```

This will also rename the files so you end up with `foo.html` instead of `foo.md.html`:

```
find / -name "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c 'markdown "${0}" > "${0%.md}.html"' {} \;
```

Comment: Don't you get file.md.html now? Instead of file.html?

Comment: @rush Why do I need `{}` at the end in both commands? Also, in the second command, it's hard to follow for me as to what happened? I didn't understand the `${0%.md}/.html` part.

Comment: Btw, I just checked. you probably wrote forward slash by mistake in `${0%.md}/.html`.

Comment: @shadyabhi The final `{}` is the input argument for the `sh -c` string, and is there accessed as `$0`. The command you don't understand strips `.md` and adds `.html`. You're probably right with escaping the `.`

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks for your reply. Honestly, I knew earlier also that it's stripping `.md` and adding `.html` but I would like to know more about it. Can you redirect me to a wiki/doc that explains this?

Comment: @shadyabhi http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve exactly what you have written is to use `markdown`'s `-o` option, which specifies the name of the output file, i.e.

```
find / -name "*.md" -type f -exec markdown -o {}.html {} \;
```

Doing it this way avoids starting a new shell just to run markdown.

Unfortunately, as Bernhard points out, doing it this way gives you files named `file.md.html` instead of `file.html`, so rush's approach is more appropriate here.

Comment: But, `markdown` doesn't have a `-o` option. I double-checked before commenting.

Comment: [markdown(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/markdown) says it does, but maybe you have a different version?

Comment: You could also use `pandoc -f markdown -t html -o...`.

Comment: Ohk, I was using http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/ and it doesn't have that.